# Regarding POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission

Tags: android

I am running app with `compileSdkVersion=33` and `targetSdkVersion=33` on one of Android real samsung device which has `Android version 13`.

Here, I am seeing an issue like Android OS/System itself shows notification popup automatically.
but as per documentation, App has full control over it when to show it after having `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` runtime permission and all.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What are you seeing? What is your expectation? What "notification popup" are you talking about? Maybe attach a screenshot or something. Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: OS shows notification popup saying, 
Bell icon and Allow <app_name> to send you notifications? with Allow and Don't allow buttons

Comment: I was getting due to Leakcanary library in debug variant of app. with release variant of app, app behaves exactly as android documentation says.

Comment: That popup is normal. It says so in the documentation. The user gets to control if the app can send notifications or not.

Comment: No, it's not normal as per my question. Please have a look again.
If App sets targetSdkVersion=33 and if we run app on Android 13, 
OS should not show this popup itself. 
App has to implement POST_NOTIFICATIONS runtime permission for posting the notification.

Comment: Are you requesting the runtime permission in your app?

Comment: Not yet, This was a test after updating targetSdkVersion=33 and run on Android 13 OS device.